# Button on ASP Repeater selected item

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to use CommandNames/CommandArguments to have an onclick event for my buttons in my repeater but I can't seem to get the event to fire on the click of the button so obviously i'm doing something silly.

My front end is like:

```
  <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCompany" OnItemCommand="rptCompanyCommand" OnItemDataBound="rptCompanyBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <ul>
                    <li><asp:Label CssClass="selectedCompany" runat="server" ID="lnkCompany"></asp:Label> <asp:Button CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ComId") %>' runat="server" ID="btnSelect" Text="Select" /></li>
                </ul>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

The back end code is:

```
   protected void loadResults()
    {
        dtVCompany = new components.db.PIDSDB.vCompanyDataTable();
        dtVCompany = taVCompany.GetCompaniesByName(txtSearch.Text + "%");
        rptCompany.DataSource = dtVCompany;
        rptCompany.DataBind();
    }

    protected void rptCompanyBound(object sender,
                                 System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView nRow = null;

        switch (e.Item.ItemType)
        {

            case ListItemType.Item:
            case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                nRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lnkCompany")).Text = "" + nRow["Company"] + "|" + nRow["ComId"];

                break;
        }
    }

    protected void rptCompanyCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Select":
                {
                    String selectedID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                }
                break;

            default:
                {

                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Unless i'm mistaken, i would've thought it'd hit my breakpoint on the line:

```
String selectedID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
```

When I click the button, however it doesn't.

Comment: Make sure you don't overwrite (DataBind()) the repeater on page load.

Comment: The databind is set on pageload though hm

Comment: Does it break on switch (e.CommandName)?

Comment: Afraid not, nothing in there hits

Comment: I think serge is right, you are databinding your repeater on every page  load. Your page_load method should look something like this if(!Page.IsPostBack) {loadResults}. Regards, Uros

Comment: But it loads there repeater in a postback - if i did that it wont load the original set of results